# mongo DB average difference

Tags: mongodb, average, difference

I am struggling with a MongoDB query in some homework. I am very new to MongoDb and so far only understand the basics. Here is the question:

> Suppose that we have full-time results data since `2001-08-01` for
>   a variety of football competitions in a mongo database collection
>   **results** which has the following fields **kick_off_date**, **competition_id**,
>   **home_team_id**, **away_team_id**, **home_score**, **away_score**.
>
> If the **competition_id** of the English Premiership is `1` and the **team_id**
>   of Everton is `5`, write the mongo query that would return the average
>   difference in goals scored and goals conceded by Everton since `2005-01-01` in >English Premiership games where they were playing away.

So far I have this:

```
db.results.find( { competition_id,: 1, away_team_id: 5, kick_off_date: { $gte : new ISODate("2005-1-1T00:00:00Z") }  } )
```

This gets the relevant data I believe where Everton are away in the premier league since `2005-01-01`. But I am at a loss as to how to approach returning the average difference in goals scored and goals conceded beyond using a spreadsheet.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You have 2 options, a map-reduce job or using the aggregation pipeline here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a caveat: like you I am new to mongoDB so although the answer given below appears to work, there may well be a more concise / performant way to acheive the same result.

Here is the sample dataset I constructed:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d62ce0e11e084bc1366195"),
    "kick_off_date" : ISODate("2005-01-16T10:35:54.985Z"),
    "competition_id" : 1,
    "home_team_id" : 1,
    "away_team_id" : 5,
    "home_score" : 1,
    "away_score" : 3
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d62cece11e084bc1366196"),
    "kick_off_date" : ISODate("2005-02-16T10:35:54.985Z"),
    "competition_id" : 1,
    "home_team_id" : 2,
    "away_team_id" : 5,
    "home_score" : 3,
    "away_score" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d62cfde11e084bc1366197"),
    "kick_off_date" : ISODate("2005-03-16T10:35:54.985Z"),
    "competition_id" : 1,
    "home_team_id" : 3,
    "away_team_id" : 5,
    "home_score" : 5,
    "away_score" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d62d0ce11e084bc1366198"),
    "kick_off_date" : ISODate("2005-04-16T10:35:54.985Z"),
    "competition_id" : 1,
    "home_team_id" : 4,
    "away_team_id" : 5,
    "home_score" : 0,
    "away_score" : 5
}
```

From this data you can see that the goal differences are:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d62ce0e11e084bc1366195"),
    "difference" : -2

    "_id" : ObjectId("54d62cece11e084bc1366196"),
    "difference" : 2

    "_id" : ObjectId("54d62cfde11e084bc1366197"),
    "difference" : 5

    "_id" : ObjectId("54d62d0ce11e084bc1366198"),
    "difference" : -5
```

Because of the negative differences in there, just adding these values together would give us a total of `0`, which is no use. So the query must take that into account and treat the negative numbers as positive to give a total of `14`. The average difference would then be: `(14/4) = 3.5`

So here is the aggregation query that does all this:

```
db.full_time_results.aggregate(
    {$match:
        {
            competition_id: 1,
            away_team_id: 5,
            kick_off_date: { $gte : ISODate("2005-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
        }
    },
    {$project:
        {
            away_team_id:1,
            difference: {$subtract:["$home_score","$away_score"]}
        }
    },
    {$group:
        {
            _id:"$away_team_id",
            avg_difference: {$avg:
                {$cond: 
                    { 
                        if: { $lt: [ "$difference", 0 ] }, 
                        then: {$multiply:["$difference", -1]}, 
                        else: "$difference" 
                    }
                }
             }
        }
    }
)
```

And finally, the result:

```
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "avg_difference" : 3.5
}
```

Comment: Brill! Thanks for taking the trouble to provide such a comprehensive answer. I still hadn't solved it. It makes complete sense now!

Comment: I am glad it was useful. It was a good learning experience for me as well. Will you accept my answer now please. You can always give the up arrow a bump as well if you like :-)

Comment: yes, gladly, but i don't have a good enough reputation to bump it up or mark as answer!

Comment: Are you sure you are signed in? As far as I am aware, everybody can mark their own question as answered and up-vote. If that is wrong then it would surely as a disincentive to answering row-rep questions, which seems unfair.

Comment: yes, I was signed in but I'm sure I didn't see an arrow to answer. But I do now and have marked as answer. I am then able to upvote it.